# how to load local js file into .hbs via <script rel> Handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have a script tag: 
rel = "localFile.js"

inside my hbs file along with html code. unfortunately, my localFile.js won't load when I res.render/send the compiled template.

Is there a good way to load local external js files into my hbs template?

Answer (score 3):

This is the way that works for me:

Inside of your server file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use('/here you put the name of the folder that you JavaScript file is located', express.static(__dirname + 'and here the path to the folder that you JavaScript file is located');
```

Example:

```
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + './../public/js'));
```

Inside of your hbs file:

```
<script src="/name of the folder that your file is located/name of your JavaScript file">
```

Example:

```
<script src="/js/validate.min.js"></script>
```

I hope that works for you =)

Cheers.